# Simple loop iterating over row of ActiveCell in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a pretty basic macro in VBA and this is my first time writing anything in it, so I'm struggling a lot. I completely know the logic of what I need to do, I just don't get VBA's syntax yet. I want to iterate over each cell in a row if the first cell in that row contains a particular substring. 
Inside the for-loop, I want to append that substring to the end of each cell in the row if that cell isn't empty. I'm not getting past my for-loop declaration

```
Sub changeRow()
Dim txt As String
txt = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1)
   If InStr(1, txt, "123") > 0 Then
    For Each b In Range(Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Select)
        If Len(b.Value) > 0 Then
            b.Value = b.Value & " 123"
        End If
    Next b
End If    
End Sub
```

Comment: What's `b` in your declaration, it should be a `Range`?

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the awful variable naming. I assumed b should be the Cell selected at each iteration.

Comment: If you have headers in the columns then you can also use `.AutoFilter` to filter the cells on search strings and then loop through the filtered range. That will be much much faster!

Imagine this. Your Excel Column has 50k Records. And let's say only two cells have `123`. In the current scenario, your loop will run 50k times to check if the cell has `123` or not. If you use Autofilter then your loop will run only 2 times!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way

```
Sub changeRow()
  Const sTxt        As String = "123"
  Dim cell          As Range

  With Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "A")
    If VarType(.Value) = vbString Then
      If InStr(.Value, sTxt) Then
        For Each cell In .EntireRow.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
          cell.Value = cell.Value & " " & sTxt
        Next cell
      End If
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

That will also add " 123" to the cell in which it is found, but not to cells containing numbers or formulas.

EDIT: There's a bald mistake in the code above. It should test that the cell in col A does not contain a formula:

```
Sub changeRow()
  Const sTxt        As String = "123"
  Dim cell          As Range

  With Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "A")
    If VarType(.Value) = vbString And Not .HasFormula Then
      If InStr(.Value, sTxt) Then
        For Each cell In .EntireRow.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
          cell.Value = cell.Value & " " & sTxt
        Next cell
      End If
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

Otherwise the SpecialCells line could generate a runtime error.

Comment: I like the use of `SpecialCells`. Of course, it's always good to test that it's not Nothing.

Comment: @ Doug: There's no need to test for a run-time error if the first cell tested is indeed a literal string. That was the point of the edit. @Xonal: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want without introducing any new variables (although I did change the uninformative "b" to `cell`:

```
Sub changeRow()
Dim txt As String
Dim cell As Excel.Range

txt = ActiveCell.EntireRow.Cells(1)
If InStr(1, txt, "123") > 0 Then
    For Each cell In Intersect(ActiveCell.EntireRow, ActiveCell.Parent.UsedRange)
        If Len(cell.Value) > 0 Then
            cell.Value = cell.Value & " 123"
        End If
    Next cell
End If
End Sub
```

It also doesn't leave any unqualified variable ranges, which is a good idea. Normally you'd avoid that by introducing a variable like `ws` to refer to the sheet you are dealing with. But this code is simple and based on the `Activecell` so I just used `Activecell.Parent` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have found a solution. I am just sticking to the fact that "your are new to VBA". If you have doubts, feel free to comment. Keeping most of your original logic in place,

```
'-- this line is very important, it keeps "in order" to write code
'-- Forces explicit declaration of all variables in a file, or allows implicit declarations of variables.
'-- please explore on that
Option Explicit

'-- writing this with more comments since you said you are new to VBA
Sub changeRow()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim b As Range
Dim activeRange As Range
Dim fullRange As Range
Dim lastColumn As Long
Dim txt As String

    '-- set current sheet into a reference object variable called WS
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    '-- similarly the range you plan to start the validation
    Set activeRange = ws.Range("B2")
    txt = activeRange.Value2

    '-- get last column in the row, 2 refers to rows 2 where you have data
    lastColumn = ws.Cells(2, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    '-- get range until the last column in the row
    Set fullRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Resize(, lastColumn)

    '-- this allows you to view the Address of this range in the Immediate Window, just to make sure you get the desired range right
    Debug.Print fullRange.Address

    If InStr(1, txt, "123") > 0 Then
        '-- iterating through each range in full range that we specified above
        For Each b In fullRange
            '-- there's no need to check this because when InStr() fails,
            '-- the compiler will not come to this validation!
            If Len(b.Value) > 0 Then
                '-- b.Offset(3) refers to 3 rows down from cell B2 which is B5
                '-- output into 5th row for demonstration purpose
                '-- you may set it back to b.Value per your requirement.
                '-- Please explore offset property of Range object
                b.Offset(3).Value = b.Value & " 123"
            End If
        Next b
   End If

   '-- release the memory allocated to these reference object variables
   '-- the order is: first ranges, then worksheet
   Set activeRange = Nothing
   Set fullRange = Nothing
   Set ws = Nothing

End Sub
```

[image]